# Can I use only `col-sm` in my entire bootstrap web app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been trying hard to grasp a good understanding of Bootstrap 4 breakpoints but I'm having some difficulties. Since the framework is developed for mobile-first, can I just use only `col-sm` or `sm` in my entire website project and allow devices to do the rest of the handling? I'm confused about when and how to use and combine `xs, sm, md, lg and xl`

Answer (score 0):

> can I just use only col-sm or sm in my entire website project and allow devices to do the rest of the handling?

Yes, you can use col-sm on your entire website. The main point to observe is that in BootStrap 4, the media queries that they use for breakpoints are added with `min-width` and not `max-width`. So when you use `col-sm-` the styles apply for every screen **ABOVE** 576px.

These are the breakpoints that bootstrap uses for xs, sm, md, lg, xlg respectively.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query for `xs` since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```